# Pub/Sub Get schema from topic

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to use schemas to validate data before publishing via Google Pub Sub in Python. I associated a schema to a topic (`gcloud pubsub topics create` with --schema flag).
In the publisher or subscribe code, is it possible to retrieve the schema class from the topic, similar to how it is possible to retrieve the encoding topic.schema_settings.encoding? Or do we need to copy/make accessible the `.proto` file and generate classes in the appropriate repos when we need to publish or parse messages?

Note: I was following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-topics-schema#python)

```
publisher_client = PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher_client.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

# Get the topic encoding type.
topic = publisher_client.get_topic(request={"topic": topic_path})
encoding = topic.schema_settings.encoding

# Instantiate a protoc-generated class defined in `us-states.proto`.
state = us_states_pb2.StateProto()
state.name = "Alaska"
state.post_abbr = "AK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve schemas e.g. `gcloud pubsub schemas [list|describe] ...`

And, as with all `gcloud` commands, they're backed by an API:

`gcloud pubsub schemas describe ... --log-http`

Can be found in [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) [`projects.schemas.get`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.schemas/get)

And, because they're part of the service's API, they are accessible through SDKs too:

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1


schema_service_client = pubsub_v1.SchemaServiceClient()

project = "..."
schema = "..."

name = f"projects/{project}/schemas/{schema}"
s = schema_service_client.get_schema(name=name)
print(s.definition)
```

`s` is type [`Schema`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.schemas#Schema)

But, you probably don't want to do this!

It would require that you build the types (programmatically) at runtime which is possible but ill-advised.

You should consider publishing your protobufs (and consider generating the language stubs) centrally, making these accessible to your developers and letting them access them for use.